# How do I use timeago.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started learning javascript for 2 weeks so I'm pretty new to it. I can't get timeago from http://timeago.yarp.com/ to work! I don't understand this line of instruction:

Now, let's attach it to your timestamps on DOM ready:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
  });
```

Where are the "timestamps on DOM ready?" This is what I've came up with so far but it isn't working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I added the double quotes in the third script tag, but it still isn't working. The code

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

is taken from the example provided in http://timeago.yarp.com/

I'm suppose to see the date displayed as 2 years ago, but all I see is July 17, 2008. I'm testing this on WAMP.

Comment: When something doesn't work, it's really helpful to describe what you expected, and what you got, that is, explain *how* it isn't working.

Comment: You're missing a `"` in your third `<script>` tag.

Comment: Your code is correct. You probably have a JS error from the previous two scripts. Have you checked the console?

Comment: Well what do you know? Turns out I forgot to change the src for jQuery to the current version I'm using because I just copy pasted that line from the Timeago website itself. It's now working after changing the source. Thanks for giving me a lead on where to start! (You told me to check the previous two scripts, that's where I saw the mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to change the src in

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

A mistake worthy of a noob, guess I just have to learn from it :)

Comment: Upvoted for self-learning. Good job! When you run into weird issues, it's good to first check the browser console for any errors. They'll usually tell you what's going on (like "object jQuery does not exist") and the line number where it happened.

Answer (score 1):

As @Box9 pointed out in a comment (why do people put answers into comments?), your third `<script>` tag is missing a closing quote after "javascript", though I would expect HTML to be forgiving enough to overlook that.

Comment: Because, as I rightly suspected, it wasn't the *right* answer ;)

Comment: I also felt that the missing double quotes wasn't the problem.. What does the instructions mean by "attach it to your timestamps on DOM ready?"